# Check if token expired in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have table tokens with columns: `user_id`, `token`, `expires_at`.

Example:

I have token: 12345, for me, and he expires at: 2018-06-05

When I generate new token, I generate up to 7 days..

How I can check this in model?

I tryied do with scope in model:

```
public function scopeExpired($query) {
    return $this->where('expires_at', '<=', Carbon::now())->exists();
}
```

But not working. Always false..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've always done stuff like this the following way. Note that you need the `expires_at` field as an attribute on your model.

```
// Probably on the user model, but pick wherever the data is
public function tokenExpired()
{
    if (Carbon::parse($this->attributes['expires_at']) < Carbon::now()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then from wherever you can call:

```
$validToken = $user->tokenExpired();

// Or realistically

if ($user->tokenExpired()) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: I get false. My token is valid up to: 2018-06-05. But today is 2018-05-29.  I need get true, but not false. false - expired.

Comment: So change the method name to `tokenNotExpired` and change the `<` to `>`? Note that using negative method names is confusing though! https://csharpdeveloper.wordpress.com/2016/01/20/roberts-rules-of-coders-8-avoid-negative-conditionals-and-method-names/. Your comment tells me my answer works (and your own code probably does to), but you just expect a different result.

Comment: Yea. Thanks very much

Comment: No problem! Just thinking about it, you could also rename the method to `tokenValid()` which is pretty clear and gives the results you expect :)